# Validate a string for positive number and normal string

Tags: java, validation, guava

I have a method in which I am accepting a String `clientid` and that has below requirements:

- `clientid` can be a positive number greater than zero. But if it is negative number or zero, then throw `IllegalArgumentException` with a message.
- `clientid` cannot be a `null` or empty string. But if it is, then throw `IllegalArgumentException`with a message.
- `clientid` can be a normal string as well. For example - it can be `abcdefgh` or any other string.

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

public Builder setClientId(String clientid) {
    checkArgument(!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(clientid), "clientid cannot not be null or an empty string, found '%s'.",
            clientid);
    try {
        final long id = Long.parseLong(clientid);
        checkArgument(id > 0, "clientid must not be negative or zero, found '%s'.", clientid);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    this.clientid = clientid;
    return this;
}
```

I cannot use Guava library greater than 11 so I cannot use `Longs.tryParse` method here so just using normal ugly way of parsing string. Is there anything I can improve here which is without try catch block? Anything from Apache Commons?

Comment: Do you have a stricter definition for a "normal string"? For example, why can't you accept `-1` as one?

Comment: A regex match that captures the sign, if any, would be neater (`"([-+]?)\\d+"`), but if you need to be concerned with overflowing a `Long`, it won't do the job. You'll need either to catch exceptions from `Long.parseLong` as you're doing or re-implement its logic yourself, substituting it's `throw`s with what you need done.

Answer (score 2):

If all negative and zero number strings are invalid, you do not necessarily have to parse it to a `long`. You can use java `regex` (regular expressions) to test if the code is negative or zero:

```
string.matches("-\\d+") // Matches all negative integers, even if they are less than `Long.MIN_VALUE`
string.equals("0") // If the string is zero
string.matches("0+") // If the string consists of a bunch of zeroes, nothing else, or even better
string.matches("0*") // If the string contains nothing except zeroes, meaning this will also match an empty string
```

So, other than that, this code looks fine to me, but parsing values is fairly expensive and catching exceptions is very expensive, so using regular expressions is probably better.